# How to solve this using numpy vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a really big input numpy array, and a dictionary. The dictionary dictates what the values in the numpy array should be updated to. I can do it using a for loop but it is very time consuming, can I use numpy vectorization to solve this?

Input:

```
arr_to_check = numpy.array([['A', 20],['B', 100],['C', 80],['D', 90], ['E', 100]]) # actual length is ~10^8
max_possible = {'A': 25, 'B': 40, 'C': 90, 'D': 50, 'F': 100, 'G': 90} # actual length is ~10^3
```

Expexted Result:

```
[['A', '20'], # do not change, because 20 < 25 --- max possible for 'A' is 25.
['B', '0'], # change to 0, because 100 > 50 --- max possible for 'B' is 40.
['C', '80'], # do not change, because 80 < 90
['D', '0'], # change to 0, because 90 > 50 --- max possible for 'D' is 50.
['E', '100' ]]
```

Here is the loop solution:

```
for i in range(arr_to_check.shape[0]):
    row = arr_to_check[i]
    if row[0] in max_possible and int(row[1]) > max_possible[row[0]]:
        row[1] = 0
```

Comment: Your first problem is that numpy arrays are homogeneous: you cannot mix data types. Your `arr_to_check` ends up being an array of strings, ruling out any further arithmetic operations.

Comment: Please consider reading: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html . Besides this, please note that Numpy does not shine for string manipulation or dictionary-based one.

Comment: Yup. I understand that. I will update the question.

Comment: Show the loop version.  We prefer to start with a clear definition of the desired action.  Be aware that `dict` access can't be 'vectorized'

Comment: added the loop version to the question. Thanks.

Comment: How big is `max_possible`  in practice (ie `len(max_possible)`) ? Some answers could be inefficient when `max_possible` is big.

Comment: Good Point. I should have mentioned that. I will update the question. Thanks @JérômeRichard for the leading questions. This helped in making the problem statement concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you've asked (**UPDATED** to simplify the code).

A few notes first:

- numpy arrays must be of homogeneous type, so the numbers you show in your question will be converted by numpy to strings to match the data type of the labels (if pandas is an option, it might allow you to have columns of numbers co-exist with distinct columns of strings).
- Though I have taken the result all the way through to match the original homogeneous data type (string), you can stop early and use the intermediate 1D numerical results if that's all you need.
- I have used `int` as the numeric type, and you can change this to `float` if required.

```py
import numpy
arr_to_check = numpy.array([['A', 20],['B', 100],['C', 80],['D', 90], ['E', 100]])
max_possible = {'A': 25, 'B': 40, 'C': 90, 'D': 50, 'F': 100, 'G': 90}
print('arr_to_check:'); print(arr_to_check)

aT = arr_to_check.T
labels = aT[0,:]
values = aT[1,:].astype(int)
print('labels:'); print(labels)
print('values:'); print(values)

for label, value in max_possible.items():
    curMask = (labels == label)
    values[curMask] *= (values[curMask] <= value)
print('values:'); print(values)

aT[1,:] = values
arr_to_check = aT.T
print('arr_to_check:'); print(arr_to_check)
```

Input:

```
arr_to_check:
[['A' '20']
 ['B' '100']
 ['C' '80']
 ['D' '90']
 ['E' '100']]
```

Output:

```
labels:
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E']
values:
[ 20 100  80  90 100]
values:
[ 20   0  80   0 100]
arr_to_check:
[['A' '20']
 ['B' '0']
 ['C' '80']
 ['D' '0']
 ['E' '100']]
```

Explanation:

- Transpose the input so that we can use vectorized operations directly on the numeric vector (`values`).
- Iterate over each key/value pair in `max_possible` and use a vectorized formula to multiply `values` by 0 if the value in `max_possible` has been breached for rows  whose label (in `labels`) matches the key in `max_possible`.
- Update the original numpy array using `values`.

Comment: This is not efficient since it runs in `O(n m)` time. Thus, it makes `10**3` comparisons comparing each a `10**8` array resulting in `10**11` string comparisons. This is a problem since string comparisons are generally slow and processors run at a frequency of few GHz so it should take few minutes to compute. Not to mentions the other additional operations and the temporary arrays that makes few GiB or RAM.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out that numpy arrays are homogeneous, your output elements will all have str. If that is ok, you can use [`apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
t = lambda x: [x[0],0] if  x[0] in max_possible and int(x[1]) > max_possible[x[0]] else x
numpy.apply_along_axis(t, 1, arr_to_check)
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` has a for loop hidden behind it. Hence, I can't use it.

Comment: This solution has the benefit of running in `O(n)` time. However, it is not vectorized so it makes the computation a bit slow. The loop is not the biggest problem but the use of the CPython interpreter on GiB data is (especially the 100_000_000 accesses from Numpy types which shout take ~1 us each).

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you should use only numbers in your numpy array.
So you could have your data like this:

```
arr_to_check = np.array([[0, 20],[1, 100],[2, 80],[3, 90], [4, 100]])
max_possible = np.array([25, 40, 90, 50, np.inf, 100, 90])
```

Here I have assumed 'A': 0, 'B': 1, ...
Note that this way, not only strings have been replaced by numbers, but dict has also been replaced by a Numpy array where max_possible[i] is max for i-th string, facilitating subsequent operations.

Now, you obtain what you want with:

```
m = max_possible.take(arr_to_check.T[0]) 
m1 = np.array([arr_to_check.T[0], np.minimum(arr_to_check.T[1], m)]) 
m1.T
```

- 1st line puts in m the max value of each key.
- 2nd line puts in m1 your keys as first row, and min of your values and max of each key
- 3rd row transposes as your result:

  array([[  0.,  20.],
  [  1.,  40.],
  [  2.,  80.],
  [  3.,  50.],
  [  4., 100.]])

Comment: Thanks, but the I am not allowed to update `arr_to_check` it is an input to my function and I must return it in the same format that I get. If I change it the way you are suggesting, I will have to do an extra step of converting 'A', 'B' to 0,1 and then vice-versa.

Comment: The conversion of the input arrays might be negligible compared to the very expensive solution proposed by others. So it may eventually worth it.  It looks like it runs in `O(n)` time which is rather good especially it since it operates on integers (faster than strings). Note using float32 can reduce the memory footprint by 2 and it should be as safe as using float64 ones.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code:

```
In [362]: %%timeit arr = arr_to_check.copy()
     ...: for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
     ...:     row = arr[i]
     ...:     if row[0] in max_possible and int(row[1]) > max_possible[row[0]]:
     ...:         row[1] = 0
     ...:         
14.1 µs ± 203 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Iterating like this on an array is slower than working with lists, so lets try a pure list solution:

```
In [372]: alist_to_check = [['A', 20],['B', 100],['C', 80],['D', 90], ['E', 100]]
     ...: max_possible = {'A': 25, 'B': 40, 'C': 90, 'D': 50, 'F': 100, 'G': 90}
```

Using a list comprehension with an if/else expression:

```
In [373]: [[k,0] if k in max_possible and v>max_possible[k] else [k,v] for k,v in alist_to_check]
Out[373]: [['A', 20], ['B', 0], ['C', 80], ['D', 0], ['E', 100]]

In [374]: timeit [[k,0] if k in max_possible and v>max_possible[k] else [k,v] for k,v in alist_to_check]
1.45 µs ± 3.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

One of the answers suggested a `apply_along_axis` - with the keys redefine at integer.  My timing came at

```
In [366]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(t, 1, arr_to_check)
108 µs ± 2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

For a small example the pure list approach is fastest.  For really large case we can probably cast it as a numpy problem that scales better, but I haven't looked at those options.

### with structured array

We could turn the list into a structured array.  This preserves the string and int dtypes:

```
In [398]: arr = np.array([tuple(kv) for kv in alist_to_check],'U10,int')

In [399]: arr
Out[399]: 
array([('A',  20), ('B', 100), ('C',  80), ('D',  90), ('E', 100)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])

In [400]: arr['f0']
Out[400]: array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], dtype='<U10')

In [401]: arr['f1']
Out[401]: array([ 20, 100,  80,  90, 100])
```

If `max_possible` is small relative to the list, it could be most efficient to iterate on its items, and set the corresponding elements of the structured array.  For example:

```
def foo(alist):
    arr = np.array([tuple(kv) for kv in alist],'U10,int')
    for k,v in max_possible.items():
        idx = np.nonzero((arr['f0']==k) & (arr['f1']>v))[0]
        arr['f1'][idx] = 0
    return arr

In [395]: foo(alist_to_check)
Out[395]: 
array([('A',  20), ('B',   0), ('C',  80), ('D',   0), ('E', 100)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

For this sample, the times aren't that great:

```
In [397]: timeit foo(alist_to_check)
102 µs ± 360 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

For a big list:

```
In [403]: biglist = alist_to_check*10000

In [409]: timeit foo(biglist)
44.1 ms ± 209 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [410]: timeit [[k,0] if k in max_possible and v>max_possible[k] else [k,v] for k,v in biglist]
14.8 ms ± 682 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Time still isn't that great.  However a big chunk of that is in creating the structured array:

```
In [411]: timeit arr = np.array([tuple(kv) for kv in biglist],'U10,int')
38.4 ms ± 49.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If we already had the structured array, I expect the times to be much better.

Curiously, making a pure string dtype array from that `biglist` takes even longer:

```
In [412]: timeit np.array(biglist)
74.2 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Still, this does make it clear that working a `dict` and string matching, lists remain competative with `numpy` solutions.  `numpy` is best for purely numeric work.

Comment: The first solution should have a pretty huge memory footprint based on the provided input size. I expect something like >8 GiB due to few CPython objects to create and the list having `10**8` items. The second is more space efficient, but runs in quadratic `O(n m)` time similar to the one of @constantstranger. Thus, I expect the provided solutions to be slow in practice (that being said, certainly not much more than others).